# Using FTP how do I rename a directory with trailing spaces?

Tags: windows, ftp, directory, rename

I have a directory on my website the has two trailing spaces (automatically created) and now I need to rename it to the same name with out the spaces.

For example:  ren "BON N ALL  " "BON N ALL"

But I keep getting;

ftp> ren "BON N ALL  " "BON N ALL"

550 BON N ALL  : The system cannot find the file specified.

I've tried using wildcards like;

ftp> ren "BON N ALL??" "BON N ALL"

550 BON N ALL??: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

ftp> ren "BON N ALL" "BON N ALL"

550 BON N ALL: The system cannot find the file specified.

ftp> ren "BON N ALL*" "BON N ALL"

550 BON N ALL*: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

This is on a windows system with IIS.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That probably means the FTP server is not fully compliant with RFCs 959 and 3659 of the FTP protocol, which allow leading and trailing spaces in pathnames.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and solved the problem using `./` on front and `/` on end name

for example:

```
RNFR ./ directory name with spaces  /
RNTO ./new_directory_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to do it with the ftp client included with windows XP with the same results, however, with the filezilla client I had no problem to rename it. [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) client use the [RNFR](http://ftpguide.com/RNFR.htm) and [RNTO](http://ftpguide.com/RNTO.htm) to rename the files successfully, but the windows comand line ftp client do not have this commands. I recomend you to change your ftp client.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  I was unable to rename it using Filezilla.  In the end I had to get the admins from my hosting provider to logon to the server and change it from a command line using the technique from this KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315226.

Comment: The Windows FTP client does use RNFR and RNTO commands.  Those are the only FTP commands available for renaming items.  The "ren" command uses RNFR/RNTO internally, which you can verify with any packet sniffer.  Do not get confused by the fact that the Windows FTP client lets the user type in DOS-style commands.  They are translated into actual FTP commands transparently.